# Specialized ruby regular expression

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a ruby script that has a reg ex, in order to exclude the text that is between []. For example the following:

`[29-5-10 : 10.05 | key=3.6]`

If in the file the preceding expression exists only once my reg ex works just fine. I need a reg ex that solves the following problem:

`[29-5-10 : 10.05 | key=3.6]`

`[29-5-10 : 10.05 | key=3.6]`

... bla ..bla

`[29-5-10 : 10.05 | key=3.6]`

My reg ex now is `/\[(.*)\]/`

Answer (score 2):

Try changing it to the following:

```
/\[([^\]]*)\]/
```

The issue with your current behavior is that `.*` is greedy, so you will match from the first `[` to the last `]`.  By changing `.*` to `[^\]]*` you will only match characters that are not `]`.

Alternatively you could use `.*?` in place of `.*`, which is lazy (matches as few characters as possible).

Answer (score 0):

As F.J mentioned you need an ungreedy matcher.

```
s = '[29-5-10 : 10.05 | key=3.6] [29-5-10 : 10.05 | key=3.6]'
m = s.scan( /\[([^\]]*)\]/ ).flatten
p *m
```

will return

```
"29-5-10 : 10.05 | key=3.6"
"29-5-10 : 10.05 | key=3.6"
```

### See [live demo here](http://cibox.org/slivu/stackoverflow?file=specialized-ruby-regular-expression.rb&lang=ruby&run=true)